# Invoke State Machine from API Gateway Call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, state-machine

Currently, I am having difficulty successfully deploying a CloudFormation Stack that contains 3 lambdas, an API Gateway and a State Machine.  I am at my wits end for trying to debug this issue and would love a second set of eyes.  The deployment fails when it attempts to construct the `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` and kicks back with:

`apiGatewayRootMethod: entered status CREATE_FAILED, reason: Invalid ARN specified in the request (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: a2ba00f1-179b-400f-a42a-f3a4e90231af; Proxy: null)`

Below is a snippet of the template used for the deployment,

```
apiGatewayRootMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      HttpMethod: "POST"
      Integration:
        CacheKeyParameters:
          - 'method.request.path.proxy'      
        Credentials: !Ref 'apiGatewayRole'
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        PassthroughBehavior: "NEVER"
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: 'method.request.path.proxy'   
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: !Sub
            - "{\"input\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))\",\"stateMachineArn\": \"${SPIStateMachine.Arn}\"}"
            - StateMachineArn: !GetAtt [ SPIStateMachine, Arn ]
        Type: "AWS"
        Uri: !Sub
          "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/StartExecution"         
      ResourceId: !GetAtt "apiGateway.RootResourceId"
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.proxy: true    
      RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"



SPIStateMachine:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
    Properties:
      StateMachineName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-state-machine
      RoleArn: !GetAtt [ StatesExecutionRole, Arn ]
      DefinitionString: 
        Fn::Sub: 
          |-
            {
                "Comment": "Calling Step Functions from Lambda SQS",
                "StartAt": "APIGatewayLambda",
                "States": {
                    "APIGatewayLambda": {            
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Resource": "${SPIApiFunction.Arn}",
                        "Catch": [
                            {
                                "ErrorEquals": ["CustomError"],
                                "Next": "PythonLambda"
                            }
                        ],
                        "End": false
                    },
                    "PythonLambda": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Comment": "This is the mandatory lambda which will process the information and possible call the PowerShell script",
                        "Resource": "${SPILambdaFunctionOne.Arn}",
                        "Next": "Needs Additional Language?"  
                    },
                    "Needs Additional Language?": {
                        "Type": "Choice",
                        "Choices": [
                            {
                                "Variable": "$.platform",
                                "StringEquals": "powerbi",
                                "Next": "PowerShellLambda"
                            },
                            {
                                "Not": {
                                    "Variable": "$.platform",
                                    "StringEquals": "powerbi"
                                },
                                "Next": "PassThrough"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "PowerShellLambda": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Comment": "This is the PowerShell Lambda, to be run for PowerBI updates",
                        "Resource": "${SPILambdaFunctionTwo.Arn}",
                        "End": true
                    },
                    "PassThrough": {
                        "Type": "Pass",
                        "End": true
                    }    
                }
            }
```

## EDIT:

`application/json: !Sub`

`- "{\"input\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))\",\"stateMachineArn\": \"${StateMachineArn}\"}"`

`- StateMachineArn: !Sub arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:SPIStateMachine`

This results in the same `apiGatewayRootMethod: entered status CREATE_FAILED, reason: Invalid ARN specified in the request (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 9585e311-69e1-4809-bc3c-f59a67a4546e; Proxy: null)`

Comment: Is it possible to debug or sniff the request just before it's sent, so you can see what the actual ARN is?

Comment: unfortunately,  I think I would need to have it deployed before that could happen right?  This is failing upon deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this doesnt work

```
   - StateMachineArn: !GetAtt [ SPIStateMachine, Arn ]
```

quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html#aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine-return-values)

> Fn::GetAtt
> Fn::GetAtt returns a value for a specified attribute of this type. The following are the available attributes and sample return values.

> Arn
> Not currently supported by AWS CloudFormation.

You can construct the ARN using [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

```
 Fn::Sub: arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:mystatemachine
```

EDIT

so the [uri](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#uri) should be in this form

```
arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:path|action/{service_api}
```

which translates in case of step function:

```
Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/StartExecution
```

and this should be in there in the cloudformation template for the arn

```
    #set($input = $input.json('$'))
{
  "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input)",
  "stateMachineArn": "<STATE_MACHINE_ARN>"
}
```

This will pass the json payload posted to API Gateway to Step Function.

You can create another URI for [describing the execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html?shortFooter=true)

```
Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/DescribeExecution
```

For this the request template would be like below

```
    requestTemplates:
      application/json:
        Fn::Sub: |-
          {
            "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:execution:${Workflow.Name}:$input.params().path.get('executionId')"
          }
```

As I described same stuff works [here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/996a5bf1ad15583d169a68ee5d013764) you can find the working example.

Comment: In the edit, I show the change but still results in the same error.

Comment: Thank you @samtoddler, I will see if this can help.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: I just checked [uri](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#uri) should in this form <arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:path|action/{service_api}>

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what goes in for subdomain.service|service and service_api, is there any way you can elaborate if I simply want to trigger the State Machine?  It was my understanding that the specifics of what state machine to trigger were contained within the request templates?

Comment: thank you for your time Sam, currently deploying.  I'll need to step away, but if these additions help with my issue, I'll be sure to upvote it and mark it as successful.

Comment: no worries I am working on a full example based on this .. will share here shortly.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again.  The documentation is not kind to the faint of heart!